# The graph doesn't appear in the scope of simulink

Tags: matlab, scope, simulink

When i run my simulink model, the scope gives me correct graph but it disapears. It only the time 9-10 is shown on plot. Can anyone help to represent the graph.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By default, only the last 5000 data points are plotted on the scope.  You almost certainly have 50000 simulation steps from 0-10s and hence are only seeing the 5000 points from 9-10s.

Use the zoom controls on the scope to view all the points after simulation, or change the scope properties to change how they appear during simulation.  How to do that is different in different versions of Simulink, but should be relatively easy for you to find.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved.